# Vert.x Java Webclient Timeout for Null headers holds connection?

Tags: connection-pooling, vert.x, timeoutexception

Vert.x - 3.5.0

I have single vert.x vertical using single web client consuming 2 different API's on same destination host.

I have connection maxPoolSize=100, keepAlive=true, connectionTimeout=9000 and request timeout =10000.

My http call is failing because of null header parameter is being passed in my code  but problem is when vert.x throws null pointer while doing POST (because of one of the null header parameter) my http connection's are getting exhausted after sometime and never released and if I do make a call after sometime it's still timing out.

1. Please suggest what am I missing here and if vert.x is doing something internally to manage connection's that is causing this issue.
2. How should we come up with number for maxPoolSize, connect timeout value provided I know my requestTimeout is 10000 and keep alive is true
3. I can fix my null header parameter issue but I am more interested what is happening to the connection pool for timeout in such scenario's - is it like not releasing the connection ?
4. How can I monitor my current connection pool utilization.

Comment: For immediate action in production: yes, fix the problem of null header. Then have you tried with 3.5.4? Also, 3.6.2 is out and WebClient implementation has been reworked. You might want to give it a try.

Comment: Appreciate your input @tsegismont

Any chance you can suggest on recommendation on other points ?

Comment: I see web client hang issue in older version's is it still there ? I am currently using version  3.5.4

Referring to this: https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/1244

Reason I am saying this is after performing the run even if I hit a single request (after an hour or so)  I am still seeing timeout.

Comment: That's a pretty old bud report, I don't think it's related. Have you tried with 3.6?